# Grep finding which of the pattern ARE NOT in the file

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm trying to find out (grep) which of my patterns from file don't appear in log file.
I have file `input.txt` which contains:

```
00123
00124
00125
00126
```

and log file `20210716.log`

```
00123
a
b
c
d
00125
00126
xy
z
...
(tons of text)
...
00127
```

When using `grep -f input.txt 20210716.log` in output i get:

```
00123
00125
00126
```

How can i output patterns from `input.txt` that don't appear in log file?, so I would like to get:

```
00124
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this `grep`:

```sh
grep -vFf file.log input.txt

00124
```

---

Or else you can use awk like this:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {seen[$1]; next} !($0 in seen)' file.log input.txt

00124
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a bit what you really want. You talk about patterns, and  matching patterns is tough. Example if your input file contains words that should be matched, you can use the following:

```
$ grep -woFf input.txt file.log | grep -vwoFf - input.txt
```

This reads the file `input.txt` as a list of patterns to search (`-f`), but these patterns are assumed to be fixed strings and not regular expressions (`-F`). We also assume that we only want to match full words (`-w`) and only output wha tis matched (`-o`). The output of this command is feed back into a pipe to `grep` where we do an inverse (`-v`) match of all found words as fixed strings (`-woFf -`).

The problem here is that if `input.txt` contains actual regular expressions, the reverse `grep` does not work (you can not search for `foo` and try to match the regex `fo*` which could appear in `input.txt`.

A more bulletproof match would be to make use of `awk`:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
     {for(r in a) a[r]+=(r~a)}
     END{for(r in a) if (a[r]==0) print r}
    ' input.txt file.log
```